# Flutter: create an Object from Type or String

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create an Object from an object type defined in **Type** or from an object name defined in **String**. The following example uses a **String** to hold the object type. But I think this is not that elegant - even with **Type**, this if block would increase dramatically for a lot of object types...

I didn't find a better solution for this yet. How can I create that object dynamically from the specified object type?

```dart
if (model == 'Event') {
  data = Event.fromMap(result);
}
else if (model == 'Content') {
  data = Content.fromMap(result);
}
else if (...) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: You can't, but you could compress your code with a switch statement in a function. Each `case` contains just a `return`.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the answer. It's not ideal, but at least a small optimization to my code above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is other approach.

```dart
class Event{
  Event.fromMap(_map){
    print('This is an event');
    print(_map);
  }
}

class Content{
  Content.fromMap(_map){
    print('This is a content');
    print(_map);
  }
}

Map<String, Function> types = {
  'Event' : (_map)=>Event.fromMap(_map),
  'Content' : (_map)=>Content.fromMap(_map),
};

void main() {
  var a = types['Event']({'test':'success_event'});
  print(a.runtimeType);
  var b = types['Content']({'test':'success_content'});
  print(b.runtimeType);
}
```

Its a bit more scalable (since only depends on add the class constructor into the map).

The explanation:

```dart
class Event{
  Event.fromMap(_map){
    print('This is an event');
    print(_map);
  }
}

class Content{
  Content.fromMap(_map){
    print('This is a content');
    print(_map);
  }
}
```

Here we are creating the test classes. nothing important.

```dart
Map<String, Function> types = {
  'Event' : (_map)=>Event.fromMap(_map),
  'Content' : (_map)=>Content.fromMap(_map),
};
```

Here we are defining a `Map`. Why? Because it allows us to access some value through some key in constant time. In this case, the keys are the Strings 'Event', 'Content', but also can be types as you wanted. For simplicity, let them be Strings. The values are `Function`'s, in this example only getting as parameter a `_map` (because the Class constructors in the example require one parameter `_map`). So, if you need more types, only add the type and the function encapsulating the constructor for that type.

```dart
void main() {
  var a = types['Event']({'test':'success_event'});
  print(a.runtimeType);
  var b = types['Content']({'test':'success_content'});
  print(b.runtimeType);
}
```

Finally you can instantiate the classes easily. Only with the type string and passing to the function the values you want (In this example a map with a key 'test').

In your example would be something like:

```dart
data = types[model](result);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This might be a solution I can life with.

Answer (score 0):

I also got stuck with a similar problem. Here's how I fixed it:

Create Objects of a class :

```
class a{ 
a.fromMap(_map){}}

class b{
b.fromMap(_map){}}

Map<String,Dynamic> obj (){
return { 
"a":a,
"b":b}
```

Now we can utilize the obj object to perform the desired operations

Hope this helps